# simplexml_load_string strange characters

Tags: php

I am having difficulty with non-standard characters using simplexml_load_string.

I have loaded an newspaper xml feed using file_get_contents. If I print to screen the contents I get a title for one of the articles as :

```
<title>&#8216;If Legault were running in Alberta, he&#8217;d be more popular&#8217;: How right-wing is the CAQ?</title>
```

If I then do this:

```
$feed = @simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

And print the results of $feed, the title has changed to:

```
[title] => â��If Legault were running in Alberta, heâ��d be more popularâ��: How right-wing is the CAQ?
```

Any advice on how to stop these characters being displayed like this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks SimpleXML is creating a UTF-8 string, which is then rendered in ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) or something close like CP-1252.

When you save the result to a file and serve that file via a web server, the browser will use the encoding declared in the file.

Including in a web page
Since your web page encoding is not UTF-8, you need to convert the string to whatever encoding you are using, eg ISO-8859-1 (latin-1).

This is easily done with iconv():

```
$xmlout = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $xmlout);
```

Saving to database
You database column is not using UTF-8 collation, so you should use iconv to convert the string to the charset that your database uses.

Assuming your database collation is the same as the encoding that you render in, you will not have to do anything when reading from the database.

Explanation
In UTF-8, a 0xc2 prefix byte is used to access the top half of the "Latin-1 Supplement" block which includes characters such as accented letters, currency symbols, fractions, superscript 2 and 3, the copyright and registered trademark symbols, and the non-breaking space.

However in ISO-8859-1, the byte 0xC2 represents an Â. So when your UTF-8 string is misinterpreted as one of those, then you get Â followed by some other nonsense character.

Answer (score 0):

This is a charset issue. it needs to be utf8, you can run utf8_decode on the content, but its better to fix this issue by matching charsets from your input (feed) to your output (html page i presume).